# How to active AsyncPostBackTrigger in Update Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, placeholder

I created a updatePanel, is include some dropdownlist and a few button and I use AsyncPostBackTrigger for not update all page when the click button or select dropdownlist. 
My page structure that an aspx page and also use user control page. I use updatePanel on UserControlPage.

Here is My code and I wish you help me:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdMonthly" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSenetIslemleriAlinanUrun1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSenetIslemleriAlinanUrun1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>       

        <asp:Button ID="btnKaydet" style="margin:10px ;" Width="100" Height="50" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" OnClick="btnKaydet_Click"/>

   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSenetIslemleriAlinanUrun1" EventName="Click"  />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnKaydet" EventName="Click"  />          
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have some knowledge on placeholder but when the click dropdown or button, page is postback and placeholder knowledge dissappear.

how to fix postback problem? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, can't really understand your problem. Try to explain better please.

Comment: When the click button, page is postback. I want to prevent this situation.

Comment: starting with the least possibility, do you have a runat="server" on html head element?

Comment: plus asyncpostbacktrigger are meant for controls outside the updatepanel, a post back initiated from updatepanel children will trigger the ajax behavior by default.